# Where is "my_ifstream >> my_char" documented?

Tags: c++

I'm using "cin >> my_char" to drop a ':' in an input record I'm trying to parse. Here is a minimal example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    char c;
    int x, y;

    cin >> hex >> x >> hex >> c >> y;
    cout << "x = " << x << "\ny = " << y << "\n";
}
```

And example usage:

```
rc@timecube:/tmp$ g++ test.cpp && echo "0000a:ffff" | ./a.out 
x = 10
y = 65535
```

This code does exactly what I want, but I don't understand why. I expected to see something like:

```
istream& operator>> (char& val);
```

in the istream reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/), but I don't.

So how is this behavior documented?

Comment: Those are the member functions. The non-member functions are [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2).

Comment: @0x499602D2: Answering in comments = Argggghhh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under [the free functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2).

Not all operators are members!

Comment: That fact was exactly what I didn't realize. Thanks.